# How to Cache bust Instagram in app browser

Tags: instagram

We've made some CSS changes lately for a client in a site and the stylesheet has a cache-busting version number in query string, like style.css?v=201912270816.  The site is updating correctly.

However, we just discovered that clicking on a link in the client's Instagram bio is still loading the older version for some people, presumably people who had clicked on the link before.

Is there some way to cache bust Instagram's in-app browser?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify something. You rename the style sheet but instagram in-app browser does not reload the css?

Comment: Sorry, close.  There were changes within the stylesheet and then we also updated the version number in the URL query string.  The latest changes in the stylesheet are not showing.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem? Facing the same issue right now, even changing the link itself from https://tayau.kz to https://tayau.kz/apps didn't work.

Comment: @zhangir-siranov - We never figured a way to bust the cache actually.  We tried three times to get help from Instagram too with no response even. I think we just had to wait it out if I recall.

Comment: Hello guys, any response from instagram or have you solved it? I am facing the same issue with my meta tags. I suppose instagram cached our meta tags and never updates it.